# processing error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32

Tags: image-processing, processing

```
myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[32], 115200);
```

what's wrong with that code?

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Please show what research was done and ask a more specific question.  Currently the question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the Console output of `printArray(Serial.list())`.

You have a single serial port "COM4" at index 0.

Any index higher than that (e.g. 32) is out of the valid array index bounds.

The code you're using has a helpful comment:

```
// if you are a Windows user, please change Serial.list()[your number]
```

Simply swap the 32 for a 0 and that should do it.

Try to read and understand the code your using: imagine what the code your reading would do and how it run, then actually run it and compare your assumptions to the actual behaviour. Use the Processing reference where you're not familiar. This will help you a lot as a programmer.

For more details see [Processing Serial reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html).